# Embedded and replicable database between microservice?

Tags: redis, architecture, microservices, scalability, rocksdb

Requirement :

- 2 High compute micro service in which 1 is producer and 1 is consumer .
- Producer service produce the 2 million key,pairs and that has to be available instantly(max 1 min) to
  the consumer service

  - Note Consumer service read the keys on demand . The avg no of read could be 50K keys per minute. As these keys are random the producer forced to write the new batch of 2 million keys again and again.
  - we have strict KPI requirements on this 1 min instant data.
  - As consumer service is having low latency requirement so it can not afford to have much network calls for reading the keys.
- I am using In Memory Cache( redis) between these 2 service . However the read/write between the
  producer and consumer creating race condition and sometimes it leads to failure and read keys.

Can you suggest some idea that which In Memory Cache or Embedded db like rocks db can help here and how to scale cache service between producer and consumer.

Comment: What is the business scenario? Is it OK if the consumer reads older keys instead of the latest ones which the producer is updating, say right now? Have evaluated a Kafka stream? Although I don't think it will be faster than the shared cache you are using, but might save you from the race condition failures.

Comment: Why not use message queue like Kafka? 1 million records per minutes will not be an issue for kafka producer. And for consumer just consume the data with a specific rates.

Comment: What are data the producer produces? How big it is ?  What do you mean by this "As to write the new batch of 2 million keys again and again." ? What happens to old ones when you write new 2 million keys? What is the time interval between producer's production?

Comment: @nitgeek Yes. So we have two batches A / B and we tried to keep one batch as active batch. So the reader always reads from the active one and Producer is writes in the inactive keys.  Now the challenge here is that 2 million keys has been written as 15 different group name by a spark job. So during the active write the redis becomes slow in nature and the keyspace_misses becomes high for read.

Comment: @Gawain  I got inspired by the kafka streams and evaluated earlier. The data is not time series data and its time bounded data and it becomes obsolete after 10 minutes. Every minute producer fetch/transform/write in to the cache. The consumers requirement is have this as batch of data for every one minute.   More over the the transform step is high compute intensive. To give a number to process 1 group of data I have to run 2 worker spark cluster with 32 G /16 Core machine. Hence I am not sure how much its gonna help by processing in kafka stream.

Comment: @cool Producer produces binary data which has avg of 15kb per key. Avg keys it generate for every minute is 2 million . We were deleting it and it becomes a bottleneck for the reads so we stopped deleting and updating and purging the older keys with the new batch for the same group(A/B). We have 2 batch in redis named A and B. At a time only one batch is active for consumer service to consume .